# Firebase Notification issue in ios with warning of replacement of server keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting an warning where the server keys are placed which says that "tokens firebase cloud replaced the server keys for sending messages. Although you can continue to use them, the server keys are no longer supported."

I tried with the cloud key but i am still unable to receive notifications. Also I tried the server keys they are also not working and still unable to receive notifications in my App.

Please let me know something so that I can receive notifications in my App.

See screenshot for reference:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByDtTMHCU39BZXVSV1RxVFhmMkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The *Firebase release* don't say anything, I think the better solution now is continue to use server key and apply this change to FCM key when we have news to work fine in next patches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging replaced the server keys with Tokens for sending notifications/messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626704/firebase-cloud-messaging-replaced-the-server-keys-with-tokens-for-sending-notifi)

Comment: Seems like a lot are experiencing an issue with this. The duplicate post I flagged is with Android, bit the issue is still the same.