# Firebase Cloud Messaging replaced the server keys with Tokens for sending notifications/messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a demo app using Firebase Cloud Messaging. However, I am facing issues with the Firebase server key. Today morning I noticed that my server key got replaced with the FCM tokens.

Screenshot : 
[image: FCM Token replaced server key]

I was having two different FCM projects in two Gmail accounts having same package name for the Android app. I thought this may be causing issue and I have deleted both the projects and changed the package name, but still no luck.

I am unable to receive the push to my device. I have researched about the issue but didn't find any solution.

Comment: i also face the same problem..

Comment: Are you receiving any errors when sending a message? I've tried it on my end, using either one doesn't have any difference. Both are valid keys for sending FCM messages.

Comment: If you deleted the app and recreated it again, then you should download the latest google-services.json file.

Comment: @looptheloop88 I have checked by replacing the latest google-services.json file but still not receiving the push. I am currently debugging for any server error code on failure.

Comment: @AL. I have checked replacing both the server key and FCM token and replacing the latest json file but no effect.

Comment: But is there any error at all? Can you try sending a message using cURL?

Comment: @FaisalShaikh - are you sending via Firebase console or FCM?

Comment: @looptheloop88 I am sending messages using FCM..I have tried sending message from Console in the same channel and it's received in the device, but with FCM implementation it's still not working.

Comment: @AL. I am sending using php cURL and there is no such error in the response array from firebase. The message was sent and response array contains success with message id.

Comment: Do post a sample of the payload you are sending and the corresponding code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the Firebase release notes, but can't find any roll out regarding this change. However, looks like the server key will be deprecated soon and will be replaced by the FCM token.

If you're having issues using the server key, then consider using the FCM token now.

Basically, you'll just need to change the value of the authorization key in the request header when sending messages to client apps.

```
Content-Type:application/json   
Authorization:key=XXXXXXXXX:APA91bHVdTcAQGdFc5bIyK_WExwd5U6uJ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that they re-use the **server key** term instead of FCM token, just upgraded to the newer version, as the following screenshot:

[image]